# Why does my asp.net application need to import its own namespace?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, namespaces

I just converted `UberSite`, a vb.net web site to a web application.  I get run-time errors saying that there is no such thing as type `foo`.  When I drill down to the page in the code-view, it gives me an error-correction suggestion: import namespace `UberSite`.

If I create a new web application and define `foo` there, there is no need to import any namespace to use `foo` in the new application.

How can this be?  Why does my web application seemingly need to import its own namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the namespace that is defined in your foo class?  It could be that it falls into a different namespace than your web application project, even though the class is included as part of that project in VS. For example:

```
namespace MySuperCoolNameSpace.Lib
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that... There are no namespace declarations within the project.  It's just `public class Foo`.  And it is vb, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry about the C# code...Does Foo conflict with a .NET framework class? That's about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: No, there is no such conflict.  It worked fine in a prior version, which was a web application with no project file.